# Is there a one-liner to find the minimum of unique entities from a matrix of multiple instances of each item?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Say, I have a matrix `A` with 2 columns - column 1 contains item ID and column 2 contains its weight:

```
A = [
3   5
2   3
2   5
1   4
3   4
2   6
1   9
3   2 ];
```

I want the output as follows:

```
items = [
1   4
2   3
3   2];
```

The code I would write to do this would be:

```
items(:,1)=unique(A(:,1));
for i=1:size(items,1)
    temp=A(A(:,1)==items(i,1),:);
    items(i,2)=min(temp(:,2));
end
```

The `items` matrix is the required output here.

I was wondering if there is a one-liner code that does this in MATLAB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

assuming your item IDs are integers starting from one, you can use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
accumarray(a(:,1), a(:,2), [], @min);
```

Comment: @Shai Thanks for your solution. Your code executes instantly, while mine takes around a minute to finish executing. Would you know why there is such a huge time difference?

Comment: you are running `unique` which sorts the array - it takes O(nlogn). Then you iterate again over all items in `A` and for each item compares against `items(i,1)` this takes O(n^2). Using `accumarray` I believe is O(n).

Comment: @Shai The `unique` finishes instantly. Its the `for` loop that takes the time.  And yeah, it probably does because of O(n^2) vs O(n) thing you mentioned. Still trying to understand your code though, how the `accumarray` works :-)

Comment: @Kristada673 you can use `profile` to see a breakdown of runtime. You can also follow the link to `accumarray` documentation that explains how it works.

Comment: @Kristada673 Why are you running your `for` loop from 1 to `size(A,1)`? It should be enough to run along only the length of ìtems`

Comment: Nice, didn't think of `accumarray`, I don't use it often enough I guess... +1 =)

Comment: @nilZ0r Oh, yes, you are right. It should have been `for i=1:size(items,1)`. Thanks. I'll edit it in the question.

Comment: @StewieGriffin well, `accumarray` is a very useful tool.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`sortrows`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html):

```
B = sortrows(A);
A_min = B([true; diff(B(:,1))~=0], :)

A_min =

     1     4
     2     3
     3     2
```

`sortrows` sorts the matrix in ascending order based on the first column, then the second. Use this new sorted vector and extract the first row, along with all rows where the first column changes (1, 2, 3).

`[true; diff(B(:,1))~=0]` is a vector containing boolean `[true false false true ...]`. `true` indicates where the elements in the first column change. This is used as a logical map to index the original array.

You should know that:

```
x = [1 2 3 4];
idx = [true false false true];
x(idx) = 
     1    4
```

Comment: @Kristada673 Try to do a search on the function `diff`. That would solve your issue I believe

Answer (score 1):

If you have an access to image processing toolbox you can do this:

```
[unique(A(:,1)),[regionprops(A(:,1),A(:,2),'MinIntensity').MinIntensity]']
```

Comment: @Shai please tell me what part of the code can not be run in Matlab

Comment: In matlab, you cannot refer to a function output: you cannot access the field `.MinIntensity` of the implicit output of `regionprops(...)`. You'll have to assign the output to a variable and only then access the field of that struct array